# I running a console application via Windows Task Scheduler but it is taking more time while running it?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am facing an issue but I couldnt able to find out the root cause of this. First of all sorry I am not clear on this.

I have an application which do call some scripts and gets the sql data from one server and add it to another server. While running it will take around 50 minutes to complete.

But when I call this application via windows task scheduler. Its running for half n hour as expected and for some reason the application is been hanged or paused (not sure what is happening) for 7 hours and after that its getting resumed and takes another 20 minutes to complete. Is there any possibility of the windows task scheduler being paused for 7 hours and resuming back? Like due to log off or any other way?

Below are the settings that is used.

```
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Application logging, add entries with timestamps at all your steps.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a virus, user config issue, or version issue. If possible, I would move the app to a different box, window version different and try again. Your new friend is Task Manager, for which you will need admin rights on most versions of windows. Find task manager under control panel. more info: on Microsoft site, keywords "task schedule", "thread priority". A more elaborate solution is to build your own baby task scheduler as a service. Said service to simply invoke you app based on current date time. An even simpler solution is to create a tiny ALWAYS RUNNING app that invokes you present app whenever by whatever rule(s) you code. [i.e. skip learning about sevices, configuring task scheduler, etc ]